# Storing multiple select option values in localStorage using select id as key

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, local-storage

**Context**

First off, I am not a developer but I have tried to explain the desired outcome...
I want to use Vanilla JS for this solution.

**The problem**

I have multiple select dropdowns on the page and ideally want to be able to store the value onchange of each of the dropdowns.

```
<select name="Value1A" id="Value1A" onchange="storeValue()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="Value1B" id="Value1B" onchange="storeValue()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Essentially I want to achieve this...

*This is of course not actual working code but hopefully explains what I am trying to do*

```
function storeValue(){
 localStorage.setItem(select.id, select.value);
}
```

i.e. I want to use the select id as the localStorage key - and onchange store the value of the option of that select field (onchange).

Any help would be really appreciated. Any questions or need to me to explain better, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass event inside your onclick handler

it will look like this

```
<select name="Value1A" id="Value1A" onchange="storeValue(event)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

After inside your storeValue function get the id from event.target like this

```
function storeValue(event){
 localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: This has the desired outcome I wanted - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> In your case you want to store and later retrieve those values.

```
 // Add id:s and values: 

  <select> // select has children -> the children are the options.
           // the children have values and id:s. 
  <option id ="1" value="0" >0</option>
  <option id ="2" value="1" >1</option>
  <option id ="3" value="2" >2</option>
  <option id ="4" value="3" >3</option>
  <option id ="5" value="4" >4</option>
  <option id ="6" value="5" >5</option>
  </select>
```

> we begin by targeting the select tag and using "onchange" everytime someone clicks on the select the function gets triggered.

The "this" is the current context i.e we will be able to find the currently clicked on child of select which is an option, using this.selectedIndex which is the index number of the currently clicked on option i.e index number will be 0 for the top option and 1 for the next etc etc.

We use the index number inside this.children i.e the children of the select and by now we know the children in this case are the option tags.

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange = function() {

    var index = this.selectedIndex; 
    // console.log(this) to see what "this" prints out. 
    // above line returns the index number of selected 
    // option

    var inputText = this.children[index].value;

    // do -> console.log(inputText); to see for your self.
    // above we use the index number on the range of options. 
    // The index number helps us find the option that was clicked.

    // Now we add .value to to retrieve the value.  

    var id = this.children[index].id;
    // same as above to retrieve id

    localStorage.setItem(id, inputText);
    // above saves variables id and inputtext to localstorage. 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've used the other solution for now as it appears to have the desired outcome I wanted.